# java spring FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I'm using Intellij to connect to Postgresql on Linux Amazon Machine via SSH.
I get next error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:443) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:217) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.prepare(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
...
```

Actually simiar error when i use PgAdmin to connect. 
Here is pg_hba.conf file:

```
localhost all all              peer
host      all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
```

listen_adress = '*'

But when i try to manipulate with remote db via intellij utilite(via SSH) it works great!

Comment: Make sure that you reloaded the server. Look into the PostgreSQL log file to learn more about your problem.

Comment: where i can find the logs?

Comment: Depends... if things are normal, you'll find the following settings in `postgresql.conf` in the PostgreSQL data directory: `log_directory` and `log_filename`.